# Run Windows 10 on Mac from custom boot drive?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, external-disk, games

My Mac has specs for Fallout 4, but it won't run with wine like the others. I don't want Windows directly installed on my Mac because it corrupted my hard drive last time, instead I want to install it on a USB 3.0/Thunderbolt drive, where I can hold down a key while booting up my Mac with it plugged in to boot Windows 10. Or something like that. What I have is a Mac with Yosemite and a Windows 10 disk, I need to get an external drive capable of this $30-$50 preferably and suggestions are appreciated.

EDIT: also, I would prefer not to enter many passwords to do this so if possible that would be preferred, if nessesary I can but it would be harder. If it was my computer I wouldn't mind risking corrupting the HD.

Answer (score 1):

[rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) is able to boot Windows from external drives, as it modifies the Mac's EFI. [Here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html) are some instructions on installing it.

Comment: 1. How do I configure an external drive to have windows on it and work with this, and 2. Am I not able to do this with boot camp?