# How to run Windows 10 from USB on Macbook?

Tags: windows, usb

I need to create a portable windows To Go workplace for my job and make it runs on a Mac computer, i tried WinToUSB tool and it didn't work, it keeps stucking at 0% when creating Windows to Go with a USB 3.0, so, is there any other way or tools that can create a WTG drive that can be boot and run on a mac?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about a mac or mac issue.

Comment: It would have been better to edit this rather than repost - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212849/run-windows-10-on-mac-from-custom-boot-drive - for future reference.