# How to run Windows 10 from USB on my Mac?

Tags: windows

I need to create a portable windows To Go workplace for my job and make it runs on a Mac computer, i tried WinToUSB tool and it didn't work, it keeps stucking at 0% when creating Windows to Go with a USB 3.0, so, is there any other way or tools that can create a WTG drive that can be boot and run on a mac?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is an ideal [situation to answer your question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/404618/how-to-run-windows-10-from-usb-on-macbook), but we run Windows 10 in VMware fusion and you can store the files on external USB. It's easy to set up, clear support path, but you have to install software and have a license for it so it's not something you can show up to the Mac and boot - leave no trace behind.

Check out the personal use license for VMware Fusion Player to get started while you wait for someone smarter than me to weigh in with how to do precisely what you ask or explain why it won't work.

- https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/evalcenter?p=fusion-player-personal

[Maybe a solution like this would help?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212849/run-windows-10-on-mac-from-custom-boot-drive)

Comment: There is also [VirtualBox for Mac](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Mac%20OS%20X%20build%20instructions) which is free

Comment: thanks, i dint' want to use a VMware to run a portable Widnows as it will be very slow. I've solved my issue, i've used AnyWinGo tool to createa portable Windows to Go drive, it's ok!   source: https://www.sysgeeker.com/alternative-to-wintousb.html

Comment: Please post your answer. I would +1 that solution. Just because a commercial tool is best for me (or some), your option will surely help others @keshi7u

Answer (score 2):

According to the Microsoft document [Windows To Go: feature overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-to-go-overview), Windows To Go was removed in Windows 10, version 2004. So you would need to ISO from a earlier version of Windows 10. However, this document also states running a Windows To Go workspace on a Mac computer is not a supported scenario

The newer model Macs can run Windows 10 from an external HDD or SSD. These types of installations are not designed to be used on multiple machines. Therefore, I assume you are not interested in this type of installation.